# how to get block information using node js

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I have used bitcoin-core package in node js to get the information about the block detail using rpc command.

For example:

```
var Client = require('bitcoin-core');

const client = new Client({ headers:'false', host:'127.0.0.1', network:'testnet', password:'xxxx',port:'18332', ssl: {
    enabled: false,
    strict: false
  }, timeout:'3000', username:'xxxx' });

client.getBlockchainInformation().then((help) => console.log(help));
```

It throws below mentioned error:

```
unhandled rejection rpcerror: not found
```

Any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code is trying to connect to a bitcoin testnet node RPC running locally (`127.0.0.1` port `18332`). Do you have one running locally?

Comment: Yes I have one running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `client.getBlockchainInformation` and the other methods exposed by the `bitcoin-core` `npm` module use [bitcoin-core's REST interface.](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/REST-interface.md) In order to use it, however, it must be enabled when you start `bitcoind` with the `-rest` flag.

> The REST API can be enabled with the -rest option.
>
> The interface runs on the same port as the JSON-RPC interface, by
>   default port 8332 for mainnet, port 18332 for testnet, and port 18443
>   for regtest.

**e.g.**:

`$ bitcoind -rest`

or in **bitcoin.conf**

```
rest=1
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me how tether node is setup like a bitcoin.

Comment: If it is unrelated to this post, please create a new question.